# creating a dictionary out of a file, and then somehow adding a 2nd value to one of the keys

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Say I got a file that is

```
1 hchen 50
2 vryzhikov 60
3 kmannock 74
4 vryzhikov 53
```

I make a dictionary of the names as keys and the scores as the values. If someone has 2 different scores, both scores would come out with that name.

Something like this:

```
hchen 50
vryzhikov 53 60
kmannock 74
```

```
infile= open("students.txt", "r")
d = {}
with open("students.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split()
        key = a[1]
        val = a[2]
        d[(key)] = val



print(d)

A = input()
print(d.get(A))
```

is it possible to get what I'm going for?

Comment: Make the value a list. If the key already exists, append to the list.

Answer (score 1):

To open a file and read it to the dictionary you can use:

```py
out = {}
with open("students.txt", "r") as f_in:
    for line in map(str.strip, f_in):
        if line == "":
            continue
        _, key, val = line.split()
        out.setdefault(key, []).append(val)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{"hchen": ["50"], "vryzhikov": ["60", "53"], "kmannock": ["74"]}
```

---

For formatted print use then:

```py
for k, v in out.items():
    print(k, *v)
```

Prints:

```
hchen 50
vryzhikov 60 53
kmannock 74
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `defaultdict` where the value type is a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
    
infile= open("students.txt", "r")
d = defaultdict(lambda: [])

with open("students.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        a = line.split()
        key = a[1]
        val = a[2]
        d[key].append(val)

print(dict(d))
```

Which would output:

```
{'hchen': ['50'], 'vryzhikov': ['60', '53'], 'kmannock': ['74']}
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid parsing the data with string manipulations, [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) from the standard library can be used. Custom columns *delimiter* can be specified, here used a white space character.

```
import csv

# result
res = {}

# open file
path = "students.txt"

with open(path, 'r', newline='') as fd:
    # rows iterator
    rows = csv.reader(fd, delimiter=" ")

    # iterate through each row and skip line number 
    for _, name, score in rows:
        if name in res:
            res[name].append(score)
        else:
            res[name] = [score]

print(res)
```